# Nested Json Array constructs un-marshalling in golang

Tags: json, go

I was mainly looking at un-marshalling the below JSON array in golang.

```
{
 "status":{"code":"SUCCESS"},
 "result": {
              "total_records":1,
              "records": [{
                            "last_modified_timestamp":1501209015807,
                            "dns_servers":null,
                            "is_secured":false,
                            "nis_domains":null,
                            "storage_platform_resource_key":"e1ee32f9-6576-11e7-82a8-00a098697714",
                            "name":"vs1",
                            "nis_servers":null,
                            "created_timestamp":1501208944094,
                            "dns_domains":null,
                            "key":"f59dacca-7379-11e7-82a8-00a098697714"
                         }]
            }
 }
```

I am looking to extract the "key" field here. Tried the below syntax but not able to successfully get what i want.

```
var dat map[string]interface{}

// Unmarshall the JSON body
if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &dat); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
svmRecordsMap := dat["result"].(map[string]interface{})["records"]
fmt.Printf("%+v", svmRecordsMap)

result := (svmRecordsMap["key"].([]interface{})[0]).(map[string]interface{})
```

Any help here would be very much appreciated. Note that i am not looking at defining corresponding structs and making a copy.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand on "not able to successfully get what i want"? What is the specific problem you're having?

Comment: Take a look at this question / answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154606/marshall-and-unmarshall-json-content-in-golang?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Marshall and UnMarshall JSON Content in GoLang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154606/marshall-and-unmarshall-json-content-in-golang)

Comment: @Adrian: I am trying to understand more on how to fetch a value from an interface{} type given the above JSON input

Comment: OK, but you have code attempting to do that, with some undisclosed problem. Can you specify what the actual problem you're having is?

Comment: I am not able to fetch the value for "key" with a map produced by svmRecordsMap := dat["result"].(map[string]interface{})["records"]. How do i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [solution](https://play.golang.org/p/P2a8RLEYlF) can give you a hint what you suppose to do to extract `key`s from this JSON without any additional `type` creation.

Comment: Thanks! But what if i just want the value of "key" of the first record under "records" ?

Comment: @Rakshith Than instead of doing `for _, l3Elem := range l3 {...` you just need to 
`var values map[string]interface{};  
err := json.Unmarshal(l3[0], &values)`

Answer (score 0):

I let you an example: https://play.golang.org/p/tReMMtGA2V

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    txt := `{
 "status":{"code":"SUCCESS"},
 "result": {
              "total_records":1,
              "records": [{
                            "last_modified_timestamp":1501209015807,
                            "dns_servers":null,
                            "is_secured":false,
                            "nis_domains":null,
                            "storage_platform_resource_key":"e1ee32f9-6576-11e7-82a8-00a098697714",
                            "name":"vs1",
                            "nis_servers":null,
                            "created_timestamp":1501208944094,
                            "dns_domains":null,
                            "key":"f59dacca-7379-11e7-82a8-00a098697714"
                         }]
            }
 }`

    var dat map[string]interface{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(txt), &dat); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    svmRecordsMap := dat["result"].(map[string]interface{})["records"]
    fmt.Printf("%+v", svmRecordsMap)

    result := (svmRecordsMap.([]interface{})[0]).(map[string]interface{})

    fmt.Println(result)

}
```

In your example have to remove the "[key]" when you access to svmRecordsMap